# R and .NET interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#

What are good examples of code linking R and ASP.NET (C# or preferably F#).

What is the best way to exchange results and test classes or wrapper classes? casts or saving to files?

This would be in the context of a server running IIS and R (Statconn probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks interesting:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RtoCSharp.aspx

Comment: Thanks, and this was my starting point. I am after examples of larger projects utilising this.